# Comunication stopped between client/server program (java)

Tags: java, server, client

I am trying to get a client to communicate with a server in java, the client just simply sends a name of a file who want to search and the server should answer if there is or not in his folder.
Here is the code I wrote.

client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class client{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, NumberFormatException, InterruptedException{
        Socket client_socket = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])); 
        System.out.println("connected\n");


        BufferedWriter netOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        netOut.write(args[2]);
        netOut.flush();

        String exist = netIn.readLine();

        System.out.println("The file you searched"+ exist);


        client_socket.close();
    }
}
```

args[0] should be used as localhost, args[1] as the port and args[2] as the name of the file you want to search.

server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class server{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        ServerSocket sock_server = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        while(true){
            Socket communication = sock_server.accept();
            System.out.println("connected!\n");

            BufferedWriter netOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(communication.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(communication.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String fileName = new String();
            fileName = netIn.readLine();

            System.out.println("The name of the file is"+fileName);

            File tempFile = new File(fileName);
            boolean exists = tempFile.exists();
            System.out.println(exists);
            if(exists){
                netOut.write("The file do exists");
                netOut.flush();
            } else {
                netOut.write("The file doesn't exist");
                netOut.flush();
            }


            communication.close();
        }    
    }
}
```

arg[0] = port of communication

What happens is that the server never sends the string that certifies the presence of the file.
I've added some println() in the server to be sure that the communication from the client to the server was ok, and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it doesn't work in your case but you can try using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` in this case which I find very useful. I tested it and works fine with your code.
So on client side you can use the below :

```
...
ObjectOutputStream netOut = new ObjectOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream netIn = new ObjectInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream());
netOut.writeObject("a_file_name");
netOut.flush();
String exist = (String)netIn.readObject();
…
```

and similarly on server side :

```
…
ObjectOutputStream netOut = new ObjectOutputStream(communication.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream netIn = new ObjectInputStream(communication.getInputStream());
String fileName = new String();
fileName = (String)netIn.readObject();
…
if(exists){
      netOut.writeObject("The file do exists");
      netOut.flush();
} else {
      netOut.writeObject("The file doesn't exist");
      netOut.flush();
}
```

As there is casting involved make sure you also catch or declare `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Yeah now it works, Is there any valid explanation of why my code didn't worked?

Comment: It could be that with `BufferedWriter` you'd possibly need to write a new-line character after your writes and before the flush to make it go through : `netOut.newLine(); `